Jest testing dates
Buen dia! estoy intentando crear tests para una clase Dates que creamos. La misma utiliza date-fns y testeo con Jest, al correr el comando y testear, me funciona perfecto en mi timezone.
El problema se presenta cuando corro mi pipeline, ya que en mi local yo tengo timezone GMT-3, pero en el pipe el timezone es 0, por lo que el valor recibido es distinto al esperado.
Como puedo mockear un timezone fijo para mis tests para que en el lugar que se ejecute, no importe el timezone sino use el mockeado?
Encontré leyendo, que podía colocar en el archivo de config de Jest (el mio es setup.js) algo asi: process.env.TZ = 'UTC'; probé con distintos TZ para que me rompa y comprobar si lo esta utilizando pero no hizo nada
Si hago un console.log del process.env.TZ me llega bien el valor al test, pero no esta aplicándose correctamente
Sin embargo no me cambia nada
describe('Format method using date-fns formats', () => {
            it('should correctly format dates using date-fns mapped formats without text', () => {
                const testDate = new Date('2024-11-15T22:30:45.000Z');

                const dateFnsFormats = [
                    { format: 'yyyy', expected: '2024' },
                    { format: 'HH:mm', expected: '19:30' },
                    { format: 'hh:mm a', expected: '07:30 PM' },
                    { format: 'dd/MM', expected: '15/11' },
                    { format: 'dd/MM/yyyy', expected: '15/11/2024' },
                    { format: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm', expected: '15/11/2024 19:30' },
                    { format: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', expected: '15/11/2024 19:30:45' },
                    { format: 'MM/dd/yyyy', expected: '11/15/2024' },
                    { format: 'yyyy-MM-dd', expected: '2024-11-15' },
                    { format: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm', expected: '2024-11-15 19:30' },
                    { format: 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:ss', expected: '2024/11/15 19:45' },
                    { format: 'Pp', expected: '11/15/2024, 7:30 PM' }
                ];

                dateFnsFormats.forEach(({ format, expected }) => {
                    const result = DateHandler.format(testDate, format);
                    expect(result).toBe(expected);
                });
            });
        });

Alguien se cruzó con algún problema similar?
De antemano muchas gracias y si necesitan algún otro dato los escucho!

Buscando, encontré lo siguiente -> https://dev.to/maxpou/how-to-mock-date-with-jest-3k4b
Tienes que agregarlo al archivo jest.config.js
process.env.TZ = 'UTC';

module.exports = {
  // ...
}

De todos modos, deja igual configurado el de setup.js
process.env.TZ = 'UTC';

Lo otro que usan bastante, es mocks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719631/how-do-i-set-a-mock-date-in-jest?page=2&tab=scoredesc

Buenas! te agradezco la respuesta, lo robé pero no me funciona tampoco, corriendolos en otro pais me rompe

Bueno @Excorpion, te agradezco lo comentado, no me funciono desde ahi, pero encontre 2 formas en las que si,

Colocandole antes del script directamente en el package.json TZ='timezone elegido'
Darle el valor directamente desde el archivo que se ejecuta en ese script (test.js) asi: process.env.TZ = 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires';

